Regarding tangent plane and assuming $F(x,y,z)$ to have continuous partial derivatives
I am reading the book Calculus by Anton Bevis Davis. Section 13.7 talks about Tangent planes and Normal vectors. It is said that
In advanced courses it is proved that if $F$ has continuous first-order partial derivatives, and if $\nabla F (x_0, y_0, z_0) \neq 0$, then near $P_0$ the graph of $F(x, y, z) = c$ is indeed a “surface” rather than some possibly exotic-looking set of points in 3-space.
I wanted to know why exactly do we need $F$ to have continuous first-order partial derivatives.
Can anyone tell give me an example of a function $F(x,y,z)$ such that for some $c$ the set of points $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $F(x,y,z)=c$ is an exotic looking set of points?

The reason is that the proof of this is totally based on The Implicit Function Theorem, which requires the function $F$ to be at least of class $C^1$ (with first-order continuous partial derivatives).

@JorgeS. I basically want to know geometrically how things can go wrong if I do not assume the partial derivative to be not continuous.

If you want the tangent plane to give a good linear approximation to the graph of a function, you need a differentiable function (see for example my YouTube videos, linked in my profile). Continuous partial derivatives give you differentiability. A simple example in your framework will be
$$F(x,y,z)=z-\sqrt{|xy|}, \quad c=0.$$
By “exotic” perhaps they intend to evoke fractal sets, which you can read about elsewhere.

Let's take a function $F:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with first order continuous partial derivatives, I will denote by $N_0(F)$ the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $F(x,y,z)=0$. Suppose that there exist $(x_0, y_0, x_0)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $(x_0, y_0, z_0)\in N_0(F)$ and $\nabla F(x_0, y_0, z_0) \not=0$, since the gradient don't vanish at $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, at least one of the first partial derivatives don't vanish at $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ as well, for simplicity suppose that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0, z_0)\not=0$, this means that $\nabla F(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is not in the $YZ$ plane.
Here is the reason of why the partial derivatives must be continuous, for  points $(x,y,z)\in N_0(F)$ close enought to $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, the gradient $\nabla F(x, y, z)$ is similar to $\nabla F(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, this means that for points close enought to $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ the gradient $\nabla F(x, y, z)$ is not in $YZ$ plane. You probably have learned that $\nabla F$ is orthogonal to the level set $N_0(F)$, in addition to our previous observation we have that

For points close enought to $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, since $\nabla F(x, y, z)$ is not in the $XZ$ plane, if you stand on the $YZ$ plane you will see that a region around $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ doesn't look like it overlap with itself (viewed from the $YZ$ plane).

The previous observation suggest that we can see a region around $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ as the image of a function of the form $h(y,z)$ (the following picture should help you to understand this point) and you may remember that the image of a function $h(y,z)$ looks like a surface.

The continuitiy of the partial derivatives allow us to say that for  points $(x,y,z)\in N_0(F)$ close enought to $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, $\nabla F(x, y, z)$ is similar to $\nabla F(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, in other words, $\nabla F(x, y, z)$ doesn't vanish and doesn't change suddenly of direction with respecto to $\nabla F(x_0, y_0, z_0)$.

It is false that a differentiable function must be $C^1$.

@TedShifrin Thanks, I forgot to add the continuity of partial derivatives at the beginning.

No, you're missing my point. The key notion is differentiability. $C^1$ implies differentiable, but the converse is false.
